# How to generate class skeleton from given C++ class definition (header) file in Vim?

Tags: vim, c++

Are there any plugins / snippets that can generate a C++ class skeleton from a given header file, for Vim?  (I tried ccimpl but there does not seem to be much information on implementing it).

Answer (score 1):

There is

- [Protodef](https://github.com/derekwyatt/vim-protodef) that'll parse the complete file (malgca gave the link to vim.sf where to find it),
- [lh-cpp](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp), but this time, you'll have to select each function and type `:GOTOIMPL` as many times as required (`:MOVETOIMPL` can move a inlined function definition from the header file to the .cpp file). Notes: This also permits to jump to the function definition, and alas, I don't support template functions and classes yet (but is it really an issue as their definitions shall be included?).

  Edit 2020: Templates specifications are now supported, in a [development branch](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp/tree/gotoimpl_with_libclang), that requires [another plugin also under development](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-clang/tree/V2Upgrade) at this time.
- [header-expander](https://github.com/Davidbrcz/header-expander), which isn't wrapped into a vim plugin yet. It should give better results as it's based on clang and not on a handmade decoding of a C++ function signature in a scripting language (viml, python, ...) -- here is [an article](http://come-david.developpez.com/tutoriels/libclang-f/) that describes how it works (in French).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=213

or

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2624

May give you what you're looking for. Failing that, you could simply define your own templates for simple c++ classes (and other structures) by creating either a `cpp.tpl` or `cpp.patterns.tpl` file, and then placing them in your `after` folder and auto running them when a cpp file is loaded.

Comment: As I understand OP's question, he wants to automatically generate empty function definitions from the (member) functions declared in a header file. I'm not sure the template solution you're describing will answer the question. May be you can add more details on the subject.